# Doubt: It says here the integral exists only if the power to x is less than one, how so?

Tags: integration, improper-integrals

[image: Question link]

Why is it that the integral only exists when $r-\alpha -1<1$ ? Please check the question link,Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you computed the antiderivative of $x^{r-a-1}$?

Comment: for $r-a-1>1$ integral is diverge.

Comment: So when it diverges, it does not exist?

Comment: Is $\mu'_r=\infty$ meaningful here?

Comment: I think it is meaningful, it is also mentioned that $\alpha >0$.

Answer (score 1):

The indefinite integral is given by
\begin{align*}
\alpha \int_1^{\infty} x^{r - \alpha - 1} dx = \alpha \frac{x^{r - \alpha}}{r - \alpha} \Big\rvert^{\infty}_1 = \frac{\alpha}{r- \alpha} (\lim_{x \to \infty} x^{r-\alpha} - 1)
\end{align*}where $\lim_{x \to \infty}x^{r-\alpha}$ converges only if $r-\alpha < 0$, i.e. $r < \alpha$.

The $r-\alpha - 1 < 1$ bit seems unnecessary. It can be simplified to say $r-\alpha < 2$, but if $r-\alpha < 0$, then it is certainly less than 2 as well. So the second condition suffices.